# Laravel test fails, but works on postman

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-passport

I have a test for a user logging out and having their token deleted.

```
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp() :void {
        parent::setUp();
        \Artisan::call('migrate',['-vvv' => true]);
        \Artisan::call('passport:install',['-vvv' => true]);
        \Artisan::call('db:seed',['-vvv' => true]);
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_user_has_tokens_removed_when_logged_out()
    {

        // login
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = factory('App\User')->create();

        $response = $this->post('/api/login', [
            'username' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);

        $token = json_decode($response->getContent())->access_token;
        $this->assertTrue(!$user->tokens->isEmpty());

        // logout
        Passport::actingAs($user, ['*']);

        $logout = $this->json('POST', 'api/logout')->withHeaders([
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token  
        ]);

        $this->assertTrue($user->tokens->isEmpty());



    }
```

First I'm creating a user and logging them in so a token is created and related to their user account.

I'm asserting that the token exists after hitting the login route, which passes.

Then I'm calling the logout route which will delete all the tokens the user has:

```
    public function logout() {

        auth()->user()->tokens()->each(function($token, $key) {
            $token->delete();
        });

        return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);

    }
```

routes/api.php

`Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');`

This assertion on the test above is failing:

`$this->assertTrue($user->tokens->isEmpty());`

If I do a `dd($user->tokens);` before the assertion to check what's going on, the token shows up - it still exists.

But If I hit this `api/logout` route with Postman, which has everything stored in MySQL, all the tokens are being deleted successfully.

I don't understand what's going on and why this test is failing. Or rather, I don't understand why the `$token->delete()` doesn't work on the test, but does via Postman. What's different?

Comment: Try reloading the user relations after the logout. e.g. `$this->assertTrue($user->fresh()->tokens->isEmpty())`

Comment: @levi - that passed. I don't know that model method, so I'll have to look it up. Can you leave an answer so I can vote up and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before executing the assert, reload the `user` model relations via `$user->fresh()`, to ensure the deleted relations are reflected in the instance.

I don't know why, but within the testing context, this is not done automatically.

Comment: I hope this testing is worth it and I gain those hours back down the road :). Thank you for your help. I didn't know about that model method or that that was a thing at all.

Comment: @good_afternoon I didn't either, until I ran into the same issue as you.